# Angularjs ng-show animate not adds animation classes

Tags: angularjs, animation

Using 1.3 beta version I am including angular-animate.js and adding ngAnimate to my module.

I have a html div element as below:

```
<div class='box-show' ng-show='isHidden'>test</div>
```

And in my css:

```
.box-show {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}

.box-show.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}

.box-show.ng-hide-add, .box-show.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}
```

I am checking the chrome inspector and can not see .ng-hide-add or .ng-hide-remove classes being added. Only .ng-hide is being added or removed.  The document says we need to  add webkit-transition to the element that we want to animate for angular adds the necessary animation classes. And I have added that so what can be the problem?  ( The above css only animates when the box is showing )

Comment: How did you solved it? I have same issue, and can't figure what is happening

Comment: use ng class if you want to make it work with css. try not to touch built in directives.

Answer (score 0):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WkUYzMk4oSk80N2Mq2lP?p=preview)

I personally don't muck around with using default `.animate` classes when playing with `ng-animate`. I recommend tossing an `.animate-show` class on your `.box-show` element, and just working your style around that. See the Plunker.

I believe what's happening is without an animate class or attribute on the element, `ng-animate` doesn't know what to do.

Example CSS:

```
  .box-show {
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity:0;
  }

  .box-show.animate-show {
    opacity:1;
  }

  .box-show.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
  .box-show.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    display:block!important;
  }

  .box-show.animate-show.ng-hide {
    opacity:0;
  }
```

Example HTML:

```
  <div class='box-show animate-show' ng-show='isHidden'>test</div>
```

Comment: No, it does not change anything...  I think there is another problem in my code... I am changing isHidden via directive called by a link. But I do not think the problem is that either... I have one custom js animation on another element. Can that be the reason?

Comment: The custom JS animation on another element wouldn't typically intefere. Are you calling isHidden from a custom binding though? For example, `angular.element( window ).bind( 'scroll', function() { scope.isHidden = true; });` would not be caught by Angular until you run `if ( !$scope.$$phase ) $scope.$apply()` following the scope update from the directive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it adding a css style for `ng-animate`

```
.box-show.ng-animate {
  opacity:0;
}
```

I don't know why but it works. After include `ng-animate` in my css, Angular began to assign the corresponding classes to the element (`ng-hide-add`, `ng-hide-remove` ...).

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me it was because I hadn't injected ngAnimate into the controller.  Took me a while to figure out this pretty basic oversight.  Hopefully this will help someone else!